# C# Passing arguments from a string.property to a function which returns a value for a variable.

Tags: c#, function, properties, type-conversion

I'm attempting to make a program that acts similarly to a google search when converting a range of measurements.

I need the program to:

1) Find the positions of the units eg "4cm to inches"

2) Identify what the units are, using unitpos = Toconvert.IndexOf(units(ref Units)) as a range will be stored in memory

3) identify what value is being converted so the function returns the appropriate unit

4) Convert the value appropriately.

The issue that i'm currently having is trying to find the position of the units. Its simple when you know what unit is being entered everytime but when the program needs to search from a range of different units its become passed me. Spent hours on it and haven't got anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions? Something like `(?<quantity>[0-9]+)(?<source>\w+) to (?<destination>\w+)`

Comment: @Kevin Gosse I'd enhance it like this:

`(?<quantity>[0-9]+)(\s)*(?<source>\w+)(\s)*(to | in | (\s)*)(\s)*(?<destination>\w+)`

where he can add all allowed "convert" verbs. 

@OP Also, stemming and lemmatization should be done for units, but that's out of the question scope.

Comment: @nemanja228  I’ve never even seen anything like what you’ve posted before. If you could explain it to me I’d appreciate it

Comment: @NoahGriffiths I've added the response as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions you can check [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/), they are used to match pattern in the text.

[Here](https://regex101.com/) is also a nice fast editor to test.

I didn't think that code fit into a comment, a crude example:

```
    string input = "4cm to inches";
    Regex expression = new Regex(@"(?<quantity>[0-9]+)(\s)*(?<source>\w+)(\s)*(to | in | (\s)*)(\s)*(?<destination>\w+)");
    Match match = expression.Match(input);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // ... Get group by name.
        string quantity = match.Groups["quantity"].Value;
        string unitSource = match.Groups["source"].Value;
        string unitDestination = match.Groups["destination"].Value;
    }
```

You can read more about stemming and lemmatization [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html). Basically it comes down to treating "inch", "inches" and other variations as a same concept.